# Changing language on taxonomy term invalidates terms path

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n, path-aliases

I have a multilingual site in Swedish and English language. Some terms had language unspecified. I changed the language to English for English terms and Swedish for Swedish terms. 
Now when I try to access the terms using taxonomy/term/33 or any other number, it gives 404 Not found error.

Does pathauto module has anything to do with it?

How can I fix this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You asked two separate questions. For *"Does pathauto module has anything to do with it?"* the answer is no. Can't have. It only adds new paths to content, sometimes delete paths it created, it does not invalidate built-in ones, and `taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term` comes from [taxonomy_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_menu/7) function of taxonomy module. Not posting this as an answer because I believe what you *really wanted* to ask is the second one, how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you @Mołot for your time but you didn't answer the important question. Why it gives 404 after changing language from Language neutral to English or Swedish and secondly how can I fix this?

Comment: I didn't answer and I know it. That's why I didn't post an answer. I only posted a comment to clarify one thing you doubted and if, after that clarification, you will remove "Does pathauto" part, feel free and encouraged to flag my comments as obsolete. In the meantime your question will still be listed as unanswered, waiting for someone who might know.